# Setting radio button values to work in a JavaScript URL script?

Tags: javascript, forms, url, search, radio-button

I currently have a Blogger search function that works by having drop down/datalist values, within a form, that mimic the Blogger labels [(preview here)](http://couleurstransmogrify.blogspot.com.au/). When you hit "search" the script generates a URL with the values (labels) that were selected by the user via the short form and immediately goes to that link, as follows:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://couleurstransmogrify.blogspot.com.au/search/label/" + document.getElementById("Colour").value + "+" + document.getElementById("Item").value + "+" + document.getElementById("Class").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>

<div id="SearchBox">
<div style="padding-bottom:3px;"><font color="#000000">Search</font>ing is as easy as 1, 2, 3...</div>
<form onsubmit="return process();">
<input type="text" name="Colour" id="Colour" value="COLOUR" list="datalist1" onfocus="if(this.value == 'COLOUR'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='COLOUR';}" />
<input type="text" name="Item" id="Item" value="ITEM" list="datalist2" onfocus="if(this.value == 'ITEM'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='ITEM';}" />
<input type="text" name="Class" id="Class" value="CLASS" list="datalist3" onfocus="if(this.value == 'CLASS'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='CLASS';}" /><br />
<input type="submit" id="Search" value="SEARCH" />
</form>
<datalist id="datalist1">
<option value="All" />
</datalist>
<datalist id="datalist2">
<option value="All" />
</datalist>
<datalist id="datalist3">
<option value="All" />
</datalist>
</div>
```

This is all good but I want to add another function within the form that includes a radio button value (or a checkbox value, whatever is easier).

The goal is to either:

**a >>>>** have two radio buttons with the values "Animated" and "All." Depending on which radio button is selected, the value will be added to the end of the URL, such as
**(URL)/search/label/All+All+All+Animated** * OR **(URL)/search/label/All+All+All+All** *

Something like:

```
Animated Only? <input type="radio" name="Animated" id="Animated" value="Animated" /> Y <input type="radio" name="Animated" id="Animated" value="All" /> N
```

OR

**b >>>>** have a checkbox with the value "Animated" when CHECKED, and no value when UNCHECKED. The purpose, the same as the above, to result in the following URL's: Checked: **(URL)/search/label/All+All+All+Animated** * OR unchecked **(URL)/search/label/All+All+All** *

- "All+All+All" - the first three 'All's are currently the only values for the datalists. I have deleted the complete lists of values/labels so as to keep this post as short as possible.

The resulting form should allow visitors to search my website by the multiple pre-defined labels (values) in the form AND the option of searching within either "All" items or "Animated" items ONLY.

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated - I'm certain this will be a simple fix to the JavaScript experts on this site. I solemnly swear I have spent a few nights trying to figure this out from the many solutions on the site but I simply do not know enough about JavaScript (and am way too tired after work) to pull out the relevant bits and piece together a new script.

Comment: Are there any reasons to build URL by yourself instead of simply submitting the form? Moreover it is not valid for two elements in DOM to have the same id `Animated`.

Comment: Mez, I would really like to help you. But you have to answer my question, because the way you are trying to send data from form is completely wrong. If some strange server-side framework enforces you to do so, I will write a solution for this. If there is no such limitation, I will show you correct way to submit the form.

Comment: Hi ElmoVanKielmo, thank you for your reply and sorry for the delay - I'm on AUEST time and have only just got home from work. I didn't write the original script, it is simply what I found and am utilising to generate the result. If you have an alternate, better way, to provide my users with the Search function as currently on the site (http://couleurstransmogrify.blogspot.com.au) PLUS the added feature of "Animated Only," then feel free to scrap what I have here. It is worth noting that the Blogger labels are case sensitive and the values of the search script will need to reflect that. Thanks!